# How to get derivative as result of Matlab ode45?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-calculus

I am using Matlab ode45 to solve system of first order differential equation presented with:

```
function f=fun(z,p)

R=1; sig=1; beta=1;

f=zeros(4,1);
f(1)=-32*1*beta/(R.^4*p(1));
f(2)=(-(2-sig)*8*f(1)/(sig.*R)-f(1)*p(2))/p(1);
f(3)=(-p(2)*f(2)+(2-sig)*(-8*f(2)/R-8*f(1)/(R.*R*p(1)))/sig-f(1)*p(3))/p(1);
f(4)=(-f(2)*p(3)-f(3)*p(2)+(2-sig)*8*(-f(3)/R-(f(2)/p(1)-p(2)*f(1))/(p(1).*p(1)*R.*R))/sig -f(1)*p(4))/p(1);
```

where f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4) are first derivatives of variables p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4). When I call this function with:

```
[zv,pv]=ode45(@fun,[1 0],[1; 0; 0; 0]);
```

As result I got variables p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), I guess that is some way of working of ode45.

But I also need values of first derivatives f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4). I tried to calculate them with Matlab `diff` function, but I got imprecise results. Is there some way to get values of derivatives f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4) directly from ode45 function?

Comment: Did you try just calling `fun` again? By design that will produce the derivatives.

Comment: Did you call `diff` with one or two arguments? The returned time span `zv` will in general not be equidistantly sampled. How large are the errors in the result of `diff` and how did you determine them?

Comment: LutzL: No, I did not try just calling fun again, do I need to change something in my code, because I think it will do the same again?


Yes, zv is not equidistantly sampled, do you mean that that can be mistake and how to make it equidistantly?. But I have analytical solutions, and I am comparing it with numerical (numerical-results of presented code). According to comparison numerical results of p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4) are the same as analytical results. That is not case for derivatives f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4), when I use diff for numerical results.

Comment: Yes, the call of `fun(zv(k),pv(k))` returns the derivatives of the solution curve at time `z=zv(k)`, because that is what the solution of an ODE $p'(z)=f(z, p(z))$ is, and these should have the same accuracy as the numerical solution.

Comment: Is that still correct if in my case I have that zv is longitudinal coordinate, I have no time in my equations. And variables: p(1) is the original variable and f(1)  is the first derivative of p(1) according to zv (f(1)=dp(1)/dzv). How would I define k in my case for the first derivative?

Comment: "time" was just a name for that coordinate, what is important is its place in the structure of the ODE. `zv` is an array of sampling points, `pv` of sampling value vectors. What you want is probably `f=fun(zv(k),pv(k,:))` and then use the value `f(1)`.

Comment: I again have some question. When I put f=fun(zv(k),pv(k,:)), where k is some value, I got only 4 values and I need number of values as for solution with ode 45 (here with shown code I have 93 values with ode45)?

Comment: You might want to try a different approach, use the `sol` structure output of the solver and `deval` function to extract position and derivative values at arbitrary points, see https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html?searchHighlight=deval&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#bu7i1mf

Comment: Otherwise, yes, that is just the derivatives to the 4-dimensional state in one point, you would have to iterate over `k` to get the values at all points.

Comment: I solved it on two ways. The first one is gradient command, the second one sol and deval (as you wrote). Do you know which of these two methods is more accurate? And which have accuracy as solution of ode45?

Comment: I think that the gradient uses order 2 derivative approximations while the deval method is as precise as the integration method, thus the better variant.

Comment: I got that gradient method is better, according to analytical solution which is solution of the best accuracy. This one with ode45, sol and deval is not so accurate. According to that do you have some advice how to get more precise solution with ode45, or some other method of solving ode instead of ode45?